# No thumbnails for GIF images in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, thumbnails, gif

I set up thumbnails for GIF images on an earlier version of Ubuntu by following [the instructions in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/627183/592472).  Since my upgrade to 17.10 I've noticed GIF thumbnails are no longer generated.

I've walked through those steps again, and ensured that:

- `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gif.thumbnailer` exists and has the correct contents.
- Imagemagick is installed.
- I've cleared the cache with `rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails`
- Running `convert mygif.gif[0] -resize 100x100 thumbnail.png` manually works.

What am I forgetting?  How do I get thumbnails for GIF images again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got gif thumbnails working again by installing the `gif-thumbnailer` package from [the `atareo/thumbnailers` repository](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/thumbnailers):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/thumbnailers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gif-thumbnailer
```

Then I cleared the thumbnail cache (`rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails`) and everything's working.

The source code seems to be in [this misnamed `git-thumbnailer` repository](https://github.com/atareao/git-thumbnailer).  I haven't entirely figured out why this solution works and the others I've tried do not; it still depends on imagemagick, but passes different options, and copies images to a temporary directory before operating on them.  Anyway, that worked for me.